# Can we fetch data from storage schema while fetching data from the public schema in Supabase?

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I  have a table `product` which has a foreign key relation with `storage.objects.id`.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqJTR.png)

From the client, I wanted to produce data along with the data of the `storage.objects`.
I was trying to do something like this

```js
supabase.from("category_display")
.select(product(*, storage.objects(*)));

// also tried 
supabase.from("category_display")
.select(product(*, objects(*)));

// also tried
supabase.from("product").select(`*, 
product_images(*) <-- bucket name
`);
```

I get null as the data value.

If I fetch product data by doing this

```js
supabase.from("product").select(`*`);
```

I get the value back

```json
[
  {
    "id": "8889b965-7992-477d-bc47-d6460f0a972a",
    "name": "Diary milk chocolate",
    "desc": null,
    "sku": null,
    "category_id": "bbb72ada-d332-429d-9aba-f881c5f6eca7",
    "inventory_id": null,
    "price": 50,
    "discount_id": null,
    "deleted_at": "2023-06-30T03:55:11.170276+00:00",
    "updated_by": null,
    "updated_at": "2023-07-03T02:27:35.231514+00:00",
    "created_at": "2023-06-30T03:55:11.170276+00:00",
    "per": "Units",
    "product_image": "1162a110-c28e-47dd-89b4-40ca393ce3f0" <--- This is col that has an reference
  },
]
```

The bucket is made public
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDmoH.png)

I have made sure that RLS policies allow us to select any data from the storage schema
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYr96.png)

I am not sure even if this is possible, as `storage` is like an s3 bucket

Comment: Supabase storage tables are not meant to be joined with public tables like that, and what you should do is to simply store image path or image URL as one of the columns of your `products` table to get the images.

Comment: Thank you  @dshukertjr
That solved my issue